# What is the default behaviour of atime?

Tags: mount, filesystem, ext4

I have an Ubuntu 11.04 installation. The `/home` directory is on a partition
which uses the `ext4` filesystem. I haven't changed the default configuration so
the filesystem is mounted at boot time with the `defaults` mount option. [`man mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mount.8.html) explains which mount options the option `defaults` implies:
`rw`, `suid`, `dev`, `exec`, `auto`, `nouser`, and `async`.

I noticed that the access time (`atime`) of a file isn't updated every time I
access a file (for example with an editor or `cat`).

I looked around in the man page of `mount` and found the following option:

> - `relatime`: Update inode access times relative to modify or change time. Access time is only updated if the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change time.

This is exactly the behaviour which I observe on my system. But the `relatime`
mount option is not enabled.

Is the behaviour described in the description of the `relatime` mount option the
default behaviour of `atime`? Does this apply to all filesystems which support
`atime`?

Comment: FYI: running the `mount` command with no options will output the currently mounted volumes, with currently active mount options (with the `defaults` option already expanded into actual values).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man mount`:

> Some of these options could be enabled or disabled by default in the system kernel. To check the current setting see the options in /proc/mounts.

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Shows that `relatime` is an option for almost all filesystem mounted, but I can't say for sure if is a default for every filesystem that supports `atime`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and tried remounting the filesystem with atime and the relatime. However I could not get ext4 to consistently record the last access time regardless of whether the file was being written to or not.
Eyeballed /proc/mounts and the only option shown by default was "rw"

Reformatted for ext3 - works perfectly now!